Cgs is ignored when computing load capacitance of CMOS inverter
I was reading the Microelectronic Circuits by Sedra and came across the content about computing equivalent load capacitence for CMOS inverter. Cgs is not shown on the image below and is not included in the computation while Cgd is present.


From my understanding, CMOS inverter operates in the saturation region and due to the channel pinch-off, Cgs should be larger than Cgd for NMOS.


I was wondering the reasoning behind this.

Because V1 is taken as an ideal voltage source, any capacitance in parallel with it is irrelevant. Both of the inverter's MOSFETs have Cgs that's in parallel with V1 (the fact that one goes to Vdd and not ground is also irrelevant, as Vdd is an ideal voltage source as well), so they have no impact on the timing.
If V1 was not an ideal voltage source, then they would matter, but then you'd be looking at the propagation delay of more than just the inverter.

Ok so that's why Cgs is included in Cg3 and Cg4 terms which represents the parasitic capacitance of the CMOS of the second inverter. That makes much more sense to me now! Though I wish the book would say that explicitly.

@YiyangYan It would be good to be more explicit about it, yeah. It took me a bit to realize why you actually want to model V1 as an ideal source here, and I'm still not sure I can completely articulate why.

I guess V1 is set to an ideal source so that the analysis can focus on what happens between the points when the output of the first inverter reaches Vdd/2 from 0 and the second inverter reaches Vdd/2 from Vdd. The goal is to figure out the underlying cause of delay between gates.

@YiyangYan  It's probably better to think of it as figuring out the delay within the gate; the delay between gates is almost always negligible as it's just speed-of-light delay from one gate to the next.
